# How do I turn off "SMART Ink"?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

[image: Screenshot]

Been toying with this can cannot figure out how to kill this stupid floating toolbar. I don't want it transparent, I want it to go away.

Comment: Do you actually need SMART Ink/SMART Notebook/SMART Meeting Pro installed?

Comment: @Karan It's not my computer, so I can't say if it's needed or not. It's a computer used in one lecture hall that I attend. The professor for my particular class was irritated by it and wanted to know how to remove it, but couldn't figure it out, nor could I. I ended up just killing the process, and had him restart the computer when he was done the lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been quite annoyed by that toolbar, and after much searching, I have concluded that there is no way to turn it off gracefully (i.e. through its own interface).  However, if you open the task manager, you can forcibly kill the process, which will close it.